# Is there a built-in way to return validated form fields in django?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'd like to get all the django form fields that passed the validation to preform partial data save at each validation attempt before returning to template with validation errors. However clean() method doesn't return any data if the there are validation errors.

Is there any simple way to get just the validated fields and pass them to save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to override the `clean` method to save the data for which there are not errors to another property, such as `self.partial_cleaned`.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no built-in way to do this? Overriding `clean` is a bit of last-resort for me here, but that's what I'm going to do if there's no other way.

Comment: @Maiiku No, I'm saying that the built-in way to do this is to override clean. That's what it's for - customising how forms handle perform their validation cycle.

Comment: Not really - since full results are returned if validation passes, and error list is populated when there are errors I was hoping for something like your `partial_cleaned` property out-of-the-box, instead of having to create some template form with overridden `clean` method that all other forms have to extend. But if that's the only way, so be it. I'll wait another day and if nobody else contributes I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Maiiku You seem to consider inheritance some sort of difficult and exotic operation. It really isn't.

Comment: Hardly. I just wanted to save another layer of complexity in already immense application. Every time you introduce a template model that overrides default functions and is implemented by all derived classes you makes the code a bit more complex to decipher for another programmer - if that can be avoided I'd rather avoid it. The problem is we seem to be overriding everything at every turn, and so at this point I'd rather explore what's already in place first.

Comment: @Maiiku What do you mean by "template model"? Forms are neither templates nor models. You'd come across this issue with any framework that is not targeted at exactly what you are doing. Django "out of the box" is for sites that are basically about CRUD content management (news sites, blogs, etc); what makes it good is that it's easy to customise, and there is usually not that much customisation to do.

Comment: I meant template in dictionary meaning not django meaning. Basically a model that all forms inherit from. By default you use `forms.ModelForm`, but if you want your forms to implement overridden method you have to create a model that inherits from `forms.ModelForm`, make your changes, and derive all your forms from this model. If you take a look at django documentation you'll find that django provides a lot of useful utility methods 'out-of-the-box', I see nothing non-standard about being able easily to access a list of validated fields, hence my original question.